# Bean initialized with FactoryBean receives the FactoryBean instead of the Obect created by it

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, factory

I'm trying to reference a bean from another with xml, sending an object produced with a FactoryBean. My problem is that the data generated by the beanFactory is, apparently a FactoryBean object and hasn't the type that should have been created by the factory.

The beans are defined like this:

```
<bean id="daFactoryBean" class="com.whatever.something.MyFactoryBean">
    [...]
</bean>

<bean id="theBeanThatProducesProblems" class="com.whatever.something.AGoodName">
    <constructor-arg ref="daFactoryBean"/>
    <constructor-arg ref="anotherBean"/>
</bean>
```

Note that "daFactoryBean" would produce objects typed "TheClassIWantToProduce". And that "theBeanThatProducesProblems" expects that type on "daFactoryBean" but it receives the Factory itself.

The factoryBean is defined like this

```
public class MyFactoryBean implements 
    FactoryBean<TheClassIWantToProduce> {
    FactoryBean([..]) { [...] }
    [...]
    @Override
    public TheClassIWantToProduce getObject() { [...] }
}
```

and the class that I need to produce is this

```
public AGoodName extends RestTemplate { 
    AGoodName(TheClassIWantToProduce foo, AnotherClassThatDoesnTComeFromAFactory foo2){
    }
}
```

The thing is that I don't exactly know how to say the spring's xml that I want the object produced by the factory, not the factory itself. As the types aren't valid, the expected value isn't being initialised. Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had to create a sub-bean that used my factory-bean

```
<bean id="daFactoryBean" class="com.whatever.something.MyFactoryBean">
    [...]
</bean>

<bean id="theBeanThatProducesProblems" class="com.whatever.something.AGoodName">
    <constructor-arg> 
        <bean id="aNewBean" factory-bean="daFactoryBean" class="com.whatever.something.TheClassIWantToProduce"/>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg ref="anotherBean"/>
</bean>
```